# What I must do to add SHA-2 MAC TLS ciphers to Firefox?

Tags: firefox, tls, sha-2

I tested the latest Firefox beta using https://cc.dcsec.uni-hannover.de/ and all ciphers supported by Firefox 25 use MAC SHA1; none of them allow SHA-2. Can this be changed? Do Mozilla have plans to use SHA-2 in the future?

Besides, when I try to access a site which supports only SHA-2 MACs, I get an error.

I tested on Ubuntu 13.10 using `ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next` to have Firefox using NSS 3.15.1 and the result was the same: no SHA256 ciphers were available. Chrome (with >= NSS 3.15.1) and Opera work fine.

I filed a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=925816) to see if I could get some reply from Firefox developers; at the [support forums](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/973305#answer-487449) things are too quiet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=925816) Firefox community is not pushing in this direction, seem to me that HMAC with SHA-2 will not be an option.

Answer (score 0):

Cipher suites with HMACs using SHA-2 have been introduced in TLS 1.2. Currently, Firefox supports only TLS 1.1. For more info on TLS 1.2 support, there is an open bug at [Mozilla's Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=480514).

As you noticed, the bug has been fixed at Firefox 25.0 beta. If you change the `security.tls.version.max` to 3 in the `about:config` page (it's in the link you provided) you can then visit https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html to test your client. At the bottom you will see that SHA-2 is supported.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Fotis That bug have an status of RESOLVED FIXED. Pls, note that I'm talking about Firefox 25 beta.

Comment: Another [reference](http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/NSS-3-15-1-brings-TLS-1-2-support-to-Firefox-1918133.html)

Comment: Isn't better to ask this at firefox / mozilla dev forum?

Comment: Ops, I'm really sorry, I was interested in this too and I was under the impression that there was still no support. I had the link in my bookmarks and just pasted it.

Comment: I create a [request/question](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/973305) in the Firefox support forum.